# PHP MongoDB Search in Sub-array

Tags: mongodb, php

Data stored in collection as below

```
 [field_1] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MongoInt64 Object
                                (
                                    [value] => 1233
                                )

                            [1] => MongoInt64 Object
                                (
                                    [value] => 1234
                                )

                        )

                )
```

I need to search 1234 in field.

I used below code in php to search

```
$param = array('field_1.fields.$' => 1234);
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the $in query criteria, to find elements within an array

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array("field_1.fields" => array('$in' => array("1234"))));
```

This will find all items that have 1234 within "fields"

$in doc: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/